# highcart tooltip always get minus

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i used multiple chart (bar and line), bar as number and line as a time, my problem is, i have configure tooltipe formatter as datetime but its tooltip for line chart always show negative number........ like this picture below :

[image]

here is my code :

```
<script>


function str_pad(i,l,s) {
var o = i.toString();
if (!s) { s = '0'; }
while (o.length < l) {
    o = s + o;
}
return o;
}

function secondsToTime(secs)
 {

        var timeToNow = secs;
        var onehour =3600;

        var hours = timeToNow / onehour;

            hours = Math.floor(hours);
        var selisih =Math.abs(timeToNow -  (hours * onehour));

            timeToNow = selisih;
        var minutes =  timeToNow/60;
            minutes = Math.floor(minutes);
            selisih = Math.abs(timeToNow - (minutes * 60));

        var second = Math.round(selisih);


        var result = str_pad(hours,2) + ':' + str_pad(minutes,2)+ ':'+str_pad(second,2);

   return result;
 }


$(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#chartdiv').highcharts({

       chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'CS Performance Email Agent'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories:[ 
        <?php 
        for ($i=0; $i <2 ; $i++) { 

        ?>
            <?php echo "day - ".$i;?>,
            <?php } ?>
        ],

        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis

        // type: 'datetime', //y-axis will be in milliseconds
     //   gridLineWidth: 1,
     //   dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute:second
     //       second: '%H:%M:%S',
     //       minute: '%H:%M:%S',
     //       hour: '%H:%M:%S',
     //       day: '%H:%M:%S',
     //       week: '%H:%M:%S',
     //       month: '%H:%M:%S',
     //       year: '%H:%M:%S'
     //   },
     //  // min: Math.min.apply(null, queueNumberArray),
     //   title: {
     //       text: ' Grand Average Time'
     //   }
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Grand Total Average Time',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        }
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'Grand Total',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} ',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },

        opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {

        formatter: function () {
            var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';

            $.each(this.points, function () {

                if (this.series.name=='Grand Total'){
                    s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ' = ' +
                   this.y  ;

                }else{

                    s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ' = ' +
                   secondsToTime(this.y) ;
                }

            });

            return s;
        },
    shared:true,

    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        x: 120,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Grand Total',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [

        <?php 
         $array_totals= (2,5,6);
        for ($i=0; $i <2 ; $i++) { 

        ?>
            <?php echo $array_totals[$i] ?>,

        <?php }?>
        ],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' '
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Grand Average Time',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [


        <?php 
        $array_seconds= (26321.87, 13243.32, 334213.12);
        for ($i=0; $i <2 ; $i++) { 

        ?>
            <?php 
            echo $array_seconds[$i];
   ?>,

        <?php }?>
        ],

        tooltip: {


        },
    }]
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you hardcode the values where you refer to php? We do not have access to your variables and series object and cannot replicate a issue.

Comment: `formatter` is not available in the series object. check the docs [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.tooltip) to see what is available.

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan , i have edited and hardcode my code. my goal is i want to show a highcart with two modes ( bar and line) bar is on number format and line is on time format. my problem is, my time format is still on double, so i must convert it to date time and show on chart. and i'm stuck on this process. y axis still show double format................

Comment: 1) You still use strings insteaf of numbers, as a result chart is not pritned. Your PHP retuns "26321.87", "13243.32", "334213.12" instead of 26321.87, 13243.32, 334213.12.